# Get a sale.order with an ID in other model [Odoo]

Tags: python, odoo, erp

In the model account_move, I have a field called "invoice_origin" that have the ID of a sale order, but I need the entire sale.order. Both models are not related. How can I search and return the entire sale.order, in the move_account file?

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
client_order_ref = fields.Char('get_sale_order().client_order_ref')

# Get a sale order with the invoice_origin field
def get_sale_order(self):
    sale_order = self.env['sale.order'].search([
        ('name', '=', self.invoice_origin)
    ])
   
    return sale_order
```

> ERROR psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column
> account_move.client_order_ref does not exist LINE 1:
> ...ier_move_reference" as "supplier_move_reference", "account_m...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed `'get_sale_order().client_order_ref'` as first parameter to `Char`, Odoo will use it as a label for `client_order_ref` field and the `get_sale_order` function will not be called.

To compute the value of a field, use the [compute](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#computed-fields) parameter

***Example:***

```
client_order_ref = fields.Char(compute='get_sale_order')

@api.depends('invoice_origin')
def get_sale_order(self):
    for move in self:
        sale_order = self.env['sale.order'].search([
            ('name', '=', move.invoice_origin)
        ])

        move.client_order_ref = sale_order.client_order_ref
```

*Note that move lines are related to sale lines with [sale_line_ids](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/sale/models/account_move_line.py#L12) field*

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Kenly. In case that I need more information from sale_order, can i use the same function? I need 2 more fields, and both are many2one fields

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use the same compute method for multiple fields. You just need to assign there values like for `client_order_ref` field

Comment: Also have in mind the Note at the end of the answer. Using the relation between the invoice lines and order lines is a much safer way to get the order(s) of an invoice. Odoo can generate one invoice for many orders, that's another thing to mention.

Comment: All right, but in that case i'll compute 3 times because I need 3 fields from sale_order. There's a better way to do it with only 1 compute?

Comment: The documentation says that **multiple fields can be computed at the same time by the same method**, just use the same method on all fields and set all of them

Comment: Odoo itself uses the same method to compute multiple [invoice fields](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/account/models/account_move.py#L232-L250)